# How to send parameter to WhereRaw() in Laravel?

Tags: sql, laravel

I have 2 tables.
paylog: account, id, orderdate.
users: acid, ownerid, password

I want to run this command
$acid ='vnt'; 
SELECT * FROM paylog WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE users.ownerid=$acid)

```
$acid = 'vnt' ; 
$paylogs = DB::table('paylog')->whereExists(function($query){
    $query->select(DB::raw(1))->from('users')->whereRaw("users.ownerid = ?", array($acid));
})->get();
```

But this got error.
Please help to solve this problem.
Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use `->where("users.ownerid", $acid)`?

Answer (score 2):

You have to make `$acid` available inside the closure:

```
function($query) use($acid) {
```